# Check if multi-value checkboxes are checked in Drupal 8 Twig Template

Tags: php, twig, drupal-8

Currently trying to see if a value is true if it is checked in a field_type multi-check box in Drupal 8 content type.

```
[X] Apple
[ ] Orange
[ ] Banana
```

Expecting the following code to return true (since apple is selected), but returns false

```
{% if node.field_fruits.value[0] == '1' %}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but it should prolly be `{% if node.field_fruits[0].value == 1 %}` instead

Answer (score 2):

If you use a file type **List (text)**, with the following **allowed values**:

```
Apple|Apple
Orange|Orange
Banana|Banana
```

Then you may access values with the following code:

**Content N°1**

```
[X] Apple
[ ] Orange
[ ] Banana
```

Twig N°1:

```
{{ node.field_fruits[0].value }} 
# Will return 'Apple'
```

**Content N°2**

```
[ ] Apple
[X] Orange
[X] Banana
```

Twig N°2:

```
{{ node.field_fruits[0].value }}
# Will return 'Orange'
```

---

To go further, the `.value` will **return the key of your List (text)** field. In my previous example, the keys where the same as the value.

*Note it's more elegant to use `|first` instead of `[0]` to access the first value of a multiple field. Eg. `{{ node.field_fruits|first.value }}`*